# How I return HTTP 404 JSON/XML response in JAX-RS (Jersey) on Tomcat?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, http-status-code-404, jersey-2.0

I have the following code:

```
@Path("/users/{id}")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public User getUser(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        User user = userDao.getUserById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

If I request for a user that doesn't exists, like `/users/1234`, with "`Accept: application/json`", this code returns an `HTTP 404` response like one would expect, but returns `Content-Type` sets to `text/html` and a body message of html. Annotation `@Produces` is ignored.

Is it a problem of code or a problem of configuration?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your `@Produces` annotation is ignored because uncaught exceptions are processed by the jax-rs runtime using a predefined (default) `ExceptionMapper` If you want to customize the returned message in case of a specific exception you can create your own `ExceptionMapper` to handle it. In your case you need one to handle the `NotFoundException` exception and query the "accept" header for the requested type of the response:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>{

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException ex){
        return Response.status(404).entity(yourMessage).type( getAcceptType()).build();
    }

    private String getAcceptType(){
         List<MediaType> accepts = headers.getAcceptableMediaTypes();
         if (accepts!=null && accepts.size() > 0) {
             //choose one
         }else {
             //return a default one like Application/json
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it. I continue throwing NotFoundException, but now mapping that exception using ExceptionMapper to setting status code and media type. It works!

Before this I tried to return an equivalent response instead throwing NotFoundException, but I have the same result, a text/html 404 response.

Is this behaviour due to if my app throws a NotFoundException the default (implicit) ExceptionMapper comes in and override response that I returns to html response?
Thanks!

Comment: After trying different solution, this is the best and correct solution. It is not obligatory to map *NotFoundException*. Just use Exception and do what you need

Comment: @Provider is very important

Answer (score 18):

You can use the Response return. Example below:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    ExampleEntity exampleEntity = getExampleEntityById(id);

    if (exampleEntity != null) {
        return Response.ok(exampleEntity).build();
    }

    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that 404 is returned by your server as it is expected that you will pass things in following form

```
/users/{id}
```

but you are passing it as

```
/users/user/{id}
```

which resource is not existing at all

try accessing resource as `/users/1234`

EDIT:

create a class like

```
class RestResponse<T>{
private String status;
private String message;
private List<T> objectList;
//gettrs and setters
}
```

now in case you want response for `User` you can create it as following

```
RestResponse<User> resp = new RestResponse<User>();
resp.setStatus("400");
resp.setMessage("User does not exist");
```

and signature of your rest method would be like following

```
public RestResponse<User> getUser(@PathParam("id") int id)
```

while in case successful response you can set things like

```
RestResponse<User> resp = new RestResponse<User>();
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
userList.add(user);//the user object you want to return
resp.setStatus("200");
resp.setMessage("User exist");
resp.setObjectList(userList);
```

Comment: URI requested updated, I made a mistake typing URI. The correct URI is users/1234 to get 404 response in html but not in JSON. My problem is not response code but format of response (content-type).

Comment: remove MediaType.APPLICATION_XML from produces and try, also make sure you are giving proper message in case user is not existing. usually we create a rest response which will contain status and message for user's request and we return the same as a response when someone tries accessing resource

Comment: I tried to remove MediaType.APPLICATION_XML from annotation @Produces and I get the same result, a 404 Response with text/html Content-Type. It's like Tomcat is overriden content-type and body message...

Comment: as i mentioned in above comment in case user is not existing you need to pass an object of a class which contains status and message there you need to set status explicitly will edit ans

Comment: Maybe I will mix two approaches (VD' & Svetlin Zarev), using an ExceptionMapper with an entity that is not only a string message but an object with some properties like status code, message, etc. Thanks!